# restart rsync in case of lack of connection

Tags: bash, backup

Once a week, I download with rsync remote server backup in my local network. 
I created a bash script to do this and I setup crontab to start once a week.

the problem is: if for any reason during the night Internet crashes, rsync stop the synchronizations.

I'm asking that rsync in case of lack of connection retry starting again.
How do I fix it?
this is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
EMAIL="myemail@gmail.com"
MAIL="$(which mail)"
RSYNC="$(which rsync)"
DATA="$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"
BackupDIR="/media/back_up/Remote_repository"

$RSYNC -avxz --bwlimit=2000 root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/backup $BackupDIR/
echo "Backup Done" | $MAIL -s "Backup of $DATA  synchronized on local network" $EMAIL
```

Answer (score 1):

rsync will return a non-zero result if it fails. So something like this:

```
backup() {
  $RSYNC -avxz --bwlimit=2000 root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/backup $BackupDIR/
}

backup
while [ ! $? ]; do
  backup
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the exit code of the `rsync` process and repeat it if you get something which is related to network problems; typically `10` for *Error in socket I/O* according to the man page, but also `23` could happen, `30`, or `35`.  Actually, I would log which value you get for a while and adjust the script accordingly:

```
while true
do
  $RSYNC -avxz --bwlimit=2000 root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/backup $BackupDIR/
  exitCode=$?
  case $exitCode in
    10)
    23)
    30)
    35)
      echo "$(date): rsync finished with a network related error: $exitCode"
      ;;
    0)
      echo "$(date): rsync finished without error"
      break  # leave the while loop
      ;;
    *)  # all other cases
      echo "$(date): rsync finished with an unexpected error: $exitCode"
      break  # we don't know whether repeating it makes sense
      ;;
  esac >> $LOGFILE
done
```